# Salesforce Callout to ExactTarget via the ExactTarget REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, callout, post

Why does the below code always get a "500 internal server error" back from ExactTarget when run anonymously from the Salesforce developer console?
*(Of course I'm using my own client id and client secret.)*

Posting this exact same JSON over to the same URL using the [REST Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en) Chrome app works great.  I get the token back.  I think I must be leaving some step out of the below apex code.  Any ideas?

```
public static HttpResponse ETPost(string URL, string Body) {
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(URL);
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setBody(Body);
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
    try {
        response = http.send(request);
    }
    Catch(System.CalloutException e) {
        System.debug('Callout error: ' + e);
    }
    return response;
}

string tokenURL = 'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken';
string JSON = '{"clientId": "My client ID","clientSecret": "My client secret"}';

HttpResponse response = ETPost(tokenURL, JSON);
System.debug(response.getBody());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing the following line of code:
`request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');`

Once I added it under the `request.setBody(Body);` line, it worked like a charm.